# Springboot accept invitation

Tags: java, spring-boot

My project consist of inviting other users to a project , let's say it's a project management web app

-The Invitation is sent via email , when the user is authenticated and logged in the project gets added.Now my problem here and im asking what is the common methods to deal of a user not logged in clicking the invitation link what should i do.
-Redirect the user to login and send invitation again?
-Force the login without user interaction
or is there some other methods . i dont have a problem in code it s just im asking of how to deal with this situation.

Here is my Code :

```
  public ResponseEntity<String> acceptInvitation(/*Long projectId, String email,*/ String uuid, Principal principal) {
        try {
            // Check if auth
            if (principal == null) {
                // If not authenticated, redirect to login
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Redirect to login page");
            }
            String authenticatedEmail = principal.getName();
            User authenticatedUser = userRepository.findByEmail(authenticatedEmail)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Authenticated user not found"));
            
            Invite invitation = invitationRepository.findInviteByInvitationCode(uuid)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Invitation not found"));

            // Check if pending
            if (invitation.getStatus() != Status.pending) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Invalid invitation status");
            }
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            if (invitation.getCreatedAt().plusHours(24).isBefore(now)) {
                // check if expired
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Invitation has expired");
            }
            
            User receiver =  userRepository.findByEmail(invitation.getReceiver().getEmail())
                    .orElseThrow(() new EntityNotFoundException("Receiver user not found"));invitation.setStatus(Status.accepted);
            invitationRepository.save(invitation);
            receiver.addProject(invitation.getProject_inv());
            userRepository.save(receiver);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Invitation accepted successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error("Error accepting invitation", e);
            return 
   ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error 
accepting invitation");
        }
    }
```

So Here Im Sending the invitation Code if the user is authenticated then i check if the user exist ,if not throw exception then i get invitation from the invitation code check it satuts if its different from pending and not expired etc if and checkif the receiver exist if it does get the user receiver and add the project to it . Now im asking about the not authenticated part what should i do if the user not logged and clicks on the link.

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve]. As written, you've shown no code, no data, no behavior, no errors... it's impossible to answer as written.

Comment: I added a picture of my function

Comment: Pictures don't help - you need to provide actual text, properly formatted. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also posting all your code, without any other context, doesn't help - you still need to explain exactly what's happening, along with sample input, observed vs expected behavior, etc.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding: you have to *show your work* - you almost got there by posting an image of code, but images don't help. You then deleted your image without adding your code properly. You need to edit your question and provide properly-formatted code (the code editor is built-in, when you edit your question). Then provide all other details, to help others help you. Not sure I can give any other advice at this point.